# Orchard CMS Search & Results List Sample

Tags: content-management-system

I've been playing around with Orchard CMS and been looking for a sample site that has a search facility similar to that of http://www.microsoft-careers.com/search/. Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to build a custom module for this - it could capture your information and then you could create views for the front-end for searching, filtering, etc.